# R - Can I loop over multiple variables in parallel?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Suppose I have the following dataset ...

```
df <- data.frame(first = sample(seq(0, 100, 1), 10), 
                 second = sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 10), 
                 third = sample(seq(0, 1000, 1), 10))
```

... and the following vector that contains titles for each variable in df.

```
titles <- c("This is the first plot", 
            "This one the second", 
            "And this is the third")
```

Now I'd like to create a barplot for each variable. Here's how I could do it manually:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
barplot(df[, 'first'], main = titles[1])
barplot(df[, 'second'], main = titles[2])
barplot(df[, 'third'], main = titles[3])
```

But I'd like to be able to do it using a for loop. Below is an example of a pseudo loop describing how I wish I could do it.

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for(x in names(df), y in titles) {
  barplot(df[, x], main = y)
}
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: You can use `for(i in seq_along(df)){` and then use the index to subset the 'titles'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
df <- data.frame(first = sample(seq(0, 100, 1), 10), 
                 second = sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 10), 
                 third = sample(seq(0, 1000, 1), 10))

titles <- c("This is the first plot", 
            "This one the second", 
            "And this is the third")

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
if(length(titles) == dim(df)[2]){
  for(i in seq(length(titles))){
    barplot(df[,i], main = titles[i])
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work. Now I'll just need to figure out how and why.